# Calabash-android scrolling in CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova, calabash

How can I scroll a CordovaWebView in Calabash?

I tried `performAction("scroll_to", 'cordovaWebView','span.hmemenutxt')`

But I either receive this output:

`{
    "bonusInformation" => [],
             "message" => "",
             "success" => true
}`

or I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Step unsuccessful:
from
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:220:in
block in perform_action
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in timeout
from
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:209:in
perform_action
from
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.2/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb:46:in
performAction
from (irb):46
```

I tried using `performAction('execute_javascript','window.scroll(0,50)')` and
`performAction('drag',150,150,150,200,90)`  - but result is the same (CordovaWebView - is't scrolling).

All these `performAction`s works in a standard WebView.

Anybody know how to scroll a CordovaWebView in Calabash-android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find solution this problem with Calabash , so I use adb shell to scrolling.

- good article for scroll with adb: http://blog.softteco.com/2011/03/android-reproducing-swipe-motion-to.html
- description for click on screen with adb: http://blog.softteco.com/2011/03/android-clickonscreenxy-shell-script.html

Comment: @Aravin please look (http://www.softteco.com/blog/android-low-level-shell-click-on-screen/)  for getting event use **adb shell getevent**